# What was the point of trying to escape after first contact with Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

After first contact with Q and little chat, Picard ordered to accelerate Enterprise with maximum acceleration possible and said, "*Let's see what this Galaxy-class starship can do.*"

Picard already saw the capabilities of Q. What made him think that he could escape even 1 Km?

Comment: so you would lay down and surrender at first site of problems?  I believe that was the point, never surrender, never give up and keep fighting for your rights (to party... for MCA, R.I.P.)

Comment: Never give up, never surrender.... wait, wrong space travel franchise

Comment: @santiagozky I heard churchill's voice while typing that out...

Comment: @Mike They surrender in last even when they could still try escaping.

Comment: @Mike Churchill wouldn't said this if the he encountered Q.

Comment: @SachinShekhar that is speculation.  You might not say that, but that isn't indicative of everyone's feelings.

Comment: Can anyone explain close vote?

Comment: There are many reason to try to run from something that can definitely catch you. One, it might not care to given the extra effort necessary. Two, the chase may provide some entertainment so to please the pursuer, and possibly leave the pursued alone.

Comment: @GorchestopherH You can always put that as an answer..

Comment: Done, and done.

Comment: @santiagozky:   No, [not the wrong franchise](http://www.blastr.com/2013-8-12/ouch-fans-vote-galaxy-quest-better-trek-movie-darkness)

Comment: @ThePopMachine Considering that "...when danger reared its ugly head, [Captain Picard] bravely turned his tail and fled" perhaps Monty Python is the correct franchise here. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At that point, it was clear that Q had the ability to manipulate space/time. However, the extent of these abilties was not known (he asks the comm stations to not make transmissions so that Q won't "hear" them). By fleeing, you can:

- Give yourself time to come up with a plan while the pursuer catches up (assuming Q didn't just appear). This can be seen with him separating the saucer section, in an attempt to save most of the other people on the ship.
- Make it too much work to bother the ship
- Picard would never just give up
- It shows that humanity will not tolerate bullying, and will try to explore in spite of dangers such as Q.

Answer (score 5):

There are many reason to try to run from something that can definitely catch you. One, the pursuer might not care to chase given the extra effort necessary. Two, the chase may provide some entertainment so to please the pursuer, and as a result may possibly choose leave the pursued alone.