# Why did cage of Q need to pursue USS Enterprise-D with a finite Warp speed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, tv, star-trek-q

[After first contact with Q, USS Enterprise-D did escape the cage of Q with Warp 9+](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/what-was-point-of-escaping-after-first-contact-with-q). The cage started the pursue course to catch Enterprise. And, it overtook Enterprise's speed quickly. It was on Warp 9.9 when Enterprise stuck at Warp 9.8. Great... afterall, it belonged to Q.

But, the problem is: Why did the cage need to move with finite Warp speed? Or, why did it even need to pursue? Q was able to transport Enterprise from one part of Galaxy to another within a moment.

Comment: Maybe it had to chase because the Q like to play games.

Comment: I didn't vote, but maybe because in that _same episode_, Q says he's testing humans?

Comment: @dlanod Because personally, I'm getting _very_ annoyed at the questions structured like "I just watched <episode>, but <question>.", which can then be completely answered by quoting from <episode>.  Especially when it's the first episode and there is no character background from other episodes.

Comment: @Sachin SE *does* give you the right to *downvote* questions you think are bad questions; you may disagree but its a perfectly valid opinion that questions which are answered in the *same episode* that raises them are not very good questions for a reference QA site.

Comment: Sachin In the same episode Q tells Picard that humanity is being _tested_, that would be the proper answer as @MichaelEdenfield pointed out.

Comment: @NominSim Its not testing.. Its playing!

Comment: @NominSim (and all), sorry, but you are all way off base. I watched that episode, and the answer may be GUESSED at but it's not AT ALL unequivocally clear from the episode.

Comment: @DVK I'm not sure what you mean, the entire episode revolves around Q *testing humanity*. That is why when the Enterprise speeds off that Q pursues them in such a way that *tests the limits of their(i.e. humanities) capabilities*.

Comment: @NominSim - Being Q, he was probably very well aware of technical characteristics of Enterprise and didn't need a radar gun to measure Enterpiris's top speed. He was testing humanity's psyche, not hardware.

Comment: @DVK I definitely agree, the test was to see how far they would push themselves when being chased by an entity of vastly superior capabilities. The idea behind the down votes though is that the entire episode revolves around Q testing/toying with humanity, therefore unless the OP is asking for something out of the scope of what the episode tells us(which doesn't appear to be the case), it is a poorly researched question (IMO).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While this is a poor, speculative answer, the nature of the Q may give us clues to the bizarre way in which they operate.

The Q technically have little to gain from Picard and the Enterprise except for amusement. To chase the ship with a cage may be part of the fun.

Why do we still choose to hunt with bows and arrows?
Why does a child block the path of an ant, just to see it change directions?

Answer (score 0):

I think simply because it was more dramatic to include a chase scene than have Q click his fingers.... and I'm not sure the writers were that worried about continuity at this point; it was the first ep. and they probably didn't know Q would be a popular character so weren't expecting to have to answer these kind of questions.

Comment: True, but answers consisting mostly of "because plot hole" tend to not be what people are looking for.